# (rEFInd) Different icon for Ubuntu Recovery

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, icons, customization, refind

I just installed rEFInd for dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04. However, there are three entries on boot.

- Windows 10
- Ubuntu
- Ubuntu Recovery

Is there a way to change the icon for Ubuntu Recovery? Right now the two Ubuntu entries share the same icon. Or at least fold it into the other Ubuntu entry (where I press F2 and I get the option to boot into recovery/single user mode/etc...)?

I looked in `refind.conf` but don't see anything for setting an icon for Ubuntu Recovery.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several procedures for changing rEFInd icons are covered in the documentation here:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#icons

My preferred method is to give the filesystem or partition a suitable name; however, that might not work for you. You might want to look into copying an icon file to the same directory as the loader and giving it a name to match the loader, but with a `.png` extension. Be aware that, because rEFInd supports multiple methods of assigning icons to loaders, there can be conflicting icons, but of course only one will be selected. Thus, if you try one method and it doesn't work, chances are that whatever IS setting the icon has a higher priority, so you should either try another.

Note also that how to change the icons varies depending on what type of a boot loader it is, and that can be revealed by the description text. Each entry should have a text-mode description that you can see when you highlight it. These normally include the path to the EFI boot loader file, or sometimes an OS-specific customized description or something specific to a BIOS-mode boot (particularly on a Mac). Since you didn't report this information, or what type of computer it is (PC or Mac) in your question, I can't know with certainty how any of your OSes is booting, and therefore what methods might work for you.